# How to add extra whitespace to my table with CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to make like this table:

[image: IMAGE 1]

but when I used this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table style="width:auto; border-collapse:collapse; display:table; border-spacing:0px;"2 cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col" style="background: url(top_pilot_rank.png) no-repeat; width:40px; height:40px;"></th>
    <th scope="col" style="background: url(top_pilot_id.png) no-repeat; width:37px; height:40px;"></th>
    <th scope="col" style="background: url(top_pilot_name.png) no-repeat; width:70px; height:40px;"></th>
    <th scope="col" style="background: url(top_pilot_hours.png) no-repeat; width:63px; height:40px; "></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="background:url(top_pilot_rank_bottom.png) no-repeat; width:40px; height:40px;"></td>
    <td style="background:url(top_pilot_id_bottom.png) no-repeat; width:37px; height:40px;"></td>
    <td style="background:url(top_pilot_name_bottom.png) no-repeat; width:70px; height:40px;"></td>
    <td style="background:url(top_pilot_hours_bottom.png) no-repeat; width:63px; height:40px;"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

it turns like this:

[image: IMAGE 1]

I set the spacing to zero to figure out the problem but it seem's like there is no problem in this code.
I need your help.

Comment: in your snippet add the full url to background imgs, and you have a typo here: `<table style="width:auto; border-collapse:collapse; display:table; border-spacing:0px;"2`

Comment: What exactly is the problem? If you want spacing between the first two columns, as it seems, what did you try to achieve that? You cannot actually set them apart (without setting all columns apart with the same amount), but you can create a good enough illusion by having padding in the cells.